# How can I unlock policies?

Tags: kittens-game

How can I unlock policies in Kittens Game, and where can I find them?

I cannot find any policies tab in science. Do I need to unlock anything?

Answer (score 1):

Policies are unlocked after researching engineering.

http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Policies

And are found in the Science tab.

http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Game+tabs